# Radio vs X-ray pulsar timing

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, radio-frequency, radiometry, pulsars

The detection and timing of pulsars is a common goal in astronomy (eg.[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3086), [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.08511)).

Typically these observations are done in the radio. I appreciate that observations are taken in the X-ray as well, but **is there a reason why radio observations are preferred?** e.g. is the timing of pulsars more precise in the radio?

Comment: There are more radio telescopes then x-ray telescopes, so you can get more time to make high resolution measurements?

Comment: Hmm perhaps. I was wondering if there was a more 'fundamental' reason

Comment: Take the RXTE for example: it is pretty competitive but being a satellite, I guess as @JonCuster that you get a lot more constraints than an instrument at the surface of the Earth.

Comment: Well, plus pulsars were originally detected with radio telescopes well before there were an x-ray telescopes, so there are lots of measurements done there already. And there are lots of high precision frequency measurement techniques easily done in the range of radio frequencies.

Comment: Why is it that they are easier done in radio frequencies?